# How can I connect one SQL SELECT statement to another?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect multiple `SELECT` statements between themselves. That is `SELECT` statement A has data that will passed to `SELECT` statement B. Then, `SELECT` statement B will have data that will passed to `SELECT` statement C.

Please help me. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: You can nest selects and you can form a union between query results. Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: This is called a `JOIN`. It's basic SQL technology, you should learn how to use it.

Comment: what statement that i can use if i want to replace join statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specification is to "connect multiple SELECT statements", and to have data returned from one SELECT "passed" to another SELECT, then I suppose using inline views (derived tables) would meet the specification. (The result from a SELECT statement can often be referenced in place of table; this construct is called an "inline view", or a "derived table" in MySQL parlance.

```
SELECT b.id
  FROM ( SELECT a.id
           FROM ( SELECT t.id
                    FROM mytable t
                 ) a
       ) b
```

We can also make use of subqueries to return sets

```
SELECT t.id AS mn
     , (SELECT t.id 
          FROM mytable t
         ORDER BY t.id DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS mx
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.id ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

We can also make use of subqueries in predicates

```
 SELECT t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.id IN ( SELECT s.id 
                    FROM mytable s
                   WHERE s.id MOD 2 > 0
                )
```

It's also possible to use JOIN operations between inline views, just like JOIN operations between tables. We typically avoid subqueries and inline views when they aren't necessary, due to the potential for significant impact to performance, as well as the addition of unnecessary complexity.

Note that we could obtain results equivalent results to the queries above, usually much more efficiently, with these queries:

```
SELECT t.id FROM mytable t
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(t.id) AS mn, MAX(t.id) AS mx FROM mytable t
```

and

```
SELECT t.id FROM mytable t WHERE t.id MOD 2
```

Absent a more detailed specification of the source data, and the actual resultset you want returned, we could pose all sorts of possible query forms, and its very likely that most of those forms will be unsuitable for your actual use case.